# In Python 3.8, how do I check if an a JSON array is sorted per a value in the array?

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, sorting

I'm using Python 3.8.  I have a JSON array with each object containing an "obj_ts" item ...

```
[
    {"obj_ts": "2020-06-06 18:06:21", ... }
    {"obj_ts": "2020-06-06 14:06:21", ... }
    {"obj_ts": "2020-06-06 12:06:21", ... }
...
]
```

How do I write a function to ensure the array is sorted in descending order by the value of the "obj_ts" objects?  In the above, the first three items in the array are sorted in descending order.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing some requirements, but I am not quite seeing the problem. Sort the list and check whether it is still equal to the original? Do you want to *check* the order (and fail otherwise) or *enforce* the order (no matter what it is before)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the `obj_ts` element of each dict in the list with the sorted list to see if it is sorted correctly:

```
lst = [
    {"obj_ts": "2020-06-06 18:06:21", 'x': 1 },
    {"obj_ts": "2020-06-06 14:06:21", 'x': 2 },
    {"obj_ts": "2020-06-06 12:06:21", 'x': 3 }
]
ok = all(l['obj_ts'] == s['obj_ts'] for l, s in zip(lst, sorted(lst, key=lambda x:x['obj_ts'], reverse=True)))
print(ok)

lst = [
    {"obj_ts": "2020-06-06 18:06:21", 'x': 1 },
    {"obj_ts": "2020-06-06 12:06:21", 'x': 3 },
    {"obj_ts": "2020-06-06 14:06:21", 'x': 2 }
]

ok = all(l['obj_ts'] == s['obj_ts'] for l, s in zip(lst, sorted(lst, key=lambda x:x['obj_ts'], reverse=True)))
print(ok)
```

Output:

```
True
False
```